Перехват сообщений Telegram Bot API при использовании Webhook
Как перехватывать на Python входящие сообщения используя requests при условии, что бот в режиме вебхука? Ответа нигде нет, но есть предположения что это возможно. К примеру, андроид-приложение Graph Messenger имеет функцию входа по токену бота и показывает диалоги с пользователями бота, при этом не сбрасывая вебхук
